# mvc3 razor first run database connection error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am working on my 1st mvc razor project. I set the project and on the 1st run I am getting an error that the _appstart.cshtml page can't connect to the database. 
I can see the db in the app_data folder and on this line of code I am getting error:

```
WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("StarterSite", "UserProfile", "UserId", "Email", true);
```

This is my 1st time working on mvc razor project, and every advice is welcome about what should I enter there.

UPDATE:
conn string in web.config:

```
 <connectionStrings>
    <add name="StarterSite" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\StarterSite.mdf;User instance=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Why you don't want to download some sample project from Web? Here is a great sample http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg685494

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your connection string is pointing to the correct location (database). You can find it in your Web.config file in your solution.

e.g.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="WebContext" connectionString="Data Source=server.local;Initial Catalog=blops.test;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=Userid;Password=password" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```